# .Left function breaks For loop and stops Subroutine

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I want to move the datalabels to the right and I am getting a reference error.

```
    For Each MyNewSrs In myChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection
       With MyNewSrs.Points(1).DataLabel
           .Left = 400
       End With
    Next MyNewSrs
```

The .Left = 400 line stops the sub. When I step into it with F8 it works just fine. I tried `DoEvents` and `Sleep 1000` but it still doesn't allow for the DataLabels to move.

What can I do?

Comment: What happens if you just use `MyNewSrs.Points(1).DataLabel.Left = 400`? (No `with`)

Comment: @BruceWayne same results. I tried that before.

Comment: Does it work if you do myChrtObj.Activate before the with?

Comment: Declare a variable of type DataLabel, set it to the particular data label, then change the .Left property of this variable. (Just so you know, it's not just you, data labels can be a pain in VBA.)

Comment: It worked with adding the myChtObj.Activate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    myChtObj.Activate
    For Each MyNewSrs In myChtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection
        With MyNewSrs.Points(1).DataLabel
             .Left = 400
        End With
    Next MyNewSrs
```

Comment: please explain how your code achieves the goal the OP is reaching for. this may seem obvious to you and other experienced programmers. If you provide clear explanation of your code it will lead to better answers on SO and also more upvotes

Comment: @Malachi - That is the OP, and he's showing what he did that seems to have fixed his issue.

Comment: I had to add the myChtObj.Activate. The code might of lost its pointer to the chart, so you have reinitialize it.